# setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled - The default is false

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, wikipedia

Try creating a new app, you can always debug it using genymotion and chrome inspect tool.

I have been trying to disable the webview of my first phonegap/cordova app from almost a month with all unsuccessful trials, but just as curious I tried to check if debugging can really  be stopped with installing the phonegap apps in app store.....to my surprise all the apps's are debuggable...n those include brand like wikipidea, whose whole bundle.js is debuggable....can any one suggest should I go ahead posting my app online or not????

Actually the solutions given by the devs only support debugging enabled/disabled in remote debugging but in genymotion its always debugable....!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are afraid that someone sneaks into your code this is the least of your worries.

Take into account that anyone with a rooted device can unzip your apk and recompile his own app without not much effort.

I think the best approach is to minimize and uglify your code including variables so it will be difficult to read and as a consequence debug your code.

Comment: malcubierre, will make sure to do that atleast...Thanks